# Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account. (I can't understand where I went wrong)

Tags: spl-associated-token-account

I am trying to call the create_associated_token_account function in my solana program. but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.also when I run my program with my client, I get the error "invalid account data for this instruction"

```
pool_address = PDA account
tokenx_mint  = token mint address
last_ata     = same with my_ata_address, comes from the transaction accounts. 
token_program = token program
```

```
let my_ata_address = spl_associated_token_account::get_associated_token_address(
                &pool_address, 
                tokenx_mint.key
            );
            
            invoke(&spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
                    &my_ata_address, 
                    &pool_address, 
                    tokenx_mint.key, 
                    token_program.key
                ), &[
                    last_ata.clone(),
                    pool_account.clone(),
                    token_program.clone(),
                    tokenx_mint.clone()
                ]
            )?;
```

I add this to the keys array in my client (I was planning to make it dynamic another time):

````
{
                pubkey: new PublicKey("GENERATED_TOKEN_ATA_ADDRESS"),
                isWritable: true,
                isSigner: false
            }```
````

Comment: Can you also update the error message from compiler or error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it! Some of the parameters are incorrect for the call, so you should do:

```
            invoke(&spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
                    &pool_address, 
                    &my_ata_address, 
                    tokenx_mint.key, 
                    token_program.key
                ), &[
                    pool_account.clone(),
                    last_ata.clone(),
                    tokenx_mint.clone(),
                    system_program.clone(),
                    token_program.clone(),
                ]
            )?;
```

And if `pool_address` is a PDA account for your program, you'll need to use `invoke_signed` along with the seeds used to derive the address.

For the instruction defined at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/65a92e6e0a4346920582d9b3893cacafd85bb017/associated-token-account/program/src/instruction.rs#L92

Answer (score 1):

The `create_associated_token_account` return type of is wrong for invoking inside program.

The `spl_associated_token_account` crate is for client only.

You have to build the instruction with account info not account meta.